# How to change the image using qml timer?

Tags: qt, qml

I have one use-case to change the image continuously using timer in QML.
I am not very familiar with QML and I have implemented a psuedo code which changes the image.
I am facing one issue, on Qml load, my UI is displaying "battery-charging-empty-icon.svg" and timer starts, for every second the counter value is incremented and respective image is shown.
But when the counter value again resets to 0, getting an error "QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/undefined"
How to solve this?

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var fileNames: [
        "battery-charging-empty-icon.svg",
        "battery-charging-full-icon.svg",
        "battery-charging-half-icon.svg"
    ]
    
    property int counter: 0
    property bool execute: qmlSample.chargingStatus //this will set from Qt-C++

    Timer {
        id: timerId
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true

        onTriggered: {
            if(execute) {
                if(counter > 2) {
                    counter = 0
                }

                imageId.source = Qt.binding(function() {
                    return "qrc:/" + fileNames[counter];
                });
                
                counter = counter + 1
            }
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: imageId

        property size size: Qt.size(100, 100)
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "qrc:/" + fileNames[counter]
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `fileNames[counter % 3]` (for 0, 1 and 2).
You should also swap the file names at index 1 and 2 if you are trying to animate a charging battery in the states of **empty** → **half-full** → **full**.

Answer (score 1):

You just have a simple logic error where you increment your counter after your check for >2. It will work if you change your timer to use this code:

```
    onTriggered: {
        if(execute) {
            counter = counter + 1
            if(counter > 2) {
                counter = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that I also removed the reassignment of imageId.source. That's unnecessary because the binding will automatically reevaluate for you once `counter` has changed.

**UPDATE**:

Sorry, my change worked, but it still allowed the counter to reach 3 temporarily, which triggers the error you are seeing. Try it this way to make sure counter never reaches 3:

```
    onTriggered: {
        if(execute) {
            counter = (counter + 1) % 3
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you JarMan for your help. The images are changing in order but, I am getting continuous error like below
QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/undefined
main.qml:42:5: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/undefined
main.qml:42:5: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/undefined

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions.

Firstly, you do not need to use `"qrc:/"` prefix. If the images are bundled in the same directory as your QML files, you should use a relative reference.

Secondly, you do not need to use an `if (execute)` guard. Instead, you should property bind the `running` property to the `execute` boolean.

Here's a mock example demonstrating this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    title: "Battery Charging Status"

    property var fileNames: ["battery-1.svg", "battery-2.svg", "battery-3.svg", "battery-4.svg"]
    property int counter: 0
    property bool execute: qmlSample.chargingStatus

    Timer {
        interval: 200
        repeat: true
        running: execute
        onTriggered: counter = (counter + 1) % fileNames.length
    }

    Image {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 100
        source: fileNames[counter]
        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
    }

    QtObject {
        id: qmlSample
        property bool chargingStatus: checkBox.checked
    }
    footer: Frame {
        CheckBox {
            id: checkBox
            checked: true
            text: "Charging Status"
        }
    }
}

// battery-1.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/battery-1-32.svg
// battery-2.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/battery-2-32.svg
// battery-3.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/battery-3-32.svg
// battery-4.svg : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/battery-4-32.svg
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)